# How to make a progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

How would one go about making a progress bar in html/css/javascript. I don't really want to use Flash. Something along the lines of what can be found here: http://dustincurtis.com/about.html

All I really want is a 'progress bar' that changes to the values I give in PHP. What would be your though process? Are there any good tutorials on this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do it by controlling the width of a div via css. Something roughly along these lines:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:50px; border:1px solid black;">
  <div id="progress-bar" style="width:50%;/*change this width */
       background-image:url(someImage.png);
       height:45px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

That width value can be sent in from php if you so desire.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking along the same lines, but I though there would somehow be another way of doing it.

Comment: For some reason I was having problems with html5 <progress> tag, your solution came in handy :)

Comment: Suggestion: Both divs should be `height:50px;`.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using HTML5 its better to make use of `<progress>` tag which was newly introduced.

```html
<progress value="22" max="100"></progress>
```

Or create a progress bar of your own.

Example written in sencha

```
if (!this.popup) {
            this.popup = new Ext.Panel({
            floating: true,
            modal: false,
            // centered:true,
            style:'background:black;opacity:0.6;margin-top:330px;',
            width: '100%',
            height: '20%',
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            html: '<p align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:12px">Downloading Data<hr noshade="noshade"size="7" style="color:#FFFFFF"></p>',

            });
}
this.popup.show('pop');
```

Comment: @TejeshAlimilli HTML5 support is limited? Millions of articles around the web, thousands of questions here. I wouldn't call that a _limited support_...

Comment: @trejder I see my 2 year old comment is not relevant now, deleted it

Answer (score 12):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Check that out, it might be what you need.

Comment: I've seen that, it's brilliant, however the only problem I would have with it is that I want to completely change its look. Which I don't think you can.

Comment: You can change its look with CSS.

Comment: Jquery UI also has a roll your own style to get close to what you want and then as mentioned, make any further tweaks with css.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `progressbar.js;` Animated progress bar control and tiny chart (sparkline)

Demo and download [link](http://bug7a.github.io/progressbar.js/)

[image]

HTML usage;

```
<div id="my-progressbar"></div>
```

Javascript usage;

```
var progressBar;

window.onload = function(){

    progressBar = new ProgressBar("my-progressbar", {'width':'100%', 'height':'3px'});
    progressBar.setPercent(60);

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Basically its this: You have three files: Your long running PHP script, a progress bar controlled by Javascript ([@SapphireSun gives an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951903/how-to-make-a-progress-bar/3951908#3951908)), and a progress script. The hard part is the Progress Script; your long script must be able to report its progress without direct communication to your progress script. This can be in the form of session id's mapped to progress meters, a database, or check of whats not finished.

The process is simple:

1. Execute your script and zero out progress bar
2. Using AJAX, query your progress script
3. Progress script must somehow check on progress
4. Change the progress bar to reflect the value
5. Clean up when finished

Answer (score 5):

I tried a simple progress bar. It is not clickable just displays the actual percentage. There's a good explication and code here: http://ruwix.com/simple-javascript-html-css-slider-progress-bar/

Answer (score 4):

Here is my approach, i've tried to keep it slim:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="noload">
    <span class="loadtext" id="loadspan">50%</span>
    <div class="load" id="loaddiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.load{    
    width: 50%;
    height: 12px;
    background: url( data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAALCAYAAAC+jufvAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwAAADsABataJCQAAABp0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAUGFpbnQuTkVUIHYzLjUuMTAw9HKhAAAAPklEQVQYV2M48Gvvf4ZDv/b9Z9j7Fcha827Df4alr1b9Z1j4YsV/BuML3v8ZTC/7/GcwuwokrG4DCceH/v8Bs2Ef1StO/o0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);  
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.noload{
    width: 100px;    
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAALCAYAAAC+jufvAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwAAADsABataJCQAAABp0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAUGFpbnQuTkVUIHYzLjUuMTAw9HKhAAAANUlEQVQYVy3EIQ4AQQgEwfn/zwghCMwGh8Tj+8yVKN0d2l00M6i70XsPmdmfu6OIQJmJqooPOu8mqi//WKcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);     
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;    
    position: relative;
}

.loadtext {
    font-family: Consolas;    
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
}
```

Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DgXM6/3/)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Infinitive progress bar using pure Javascript

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:5px; border:1px solid black;">
  <div id="progress-bar" style="width:10%;background-color: green; height:5px;"></div>
</div>

<script>
  var width = 0;
  window.onload = function(e){ 
    setInterval(function () {
        width = width >= 100 ? 0 : width+5;  
        document.getElementById('progress-bar').style.width = width + '%'; }, 200);            
  }
</script>
```

Example http://fiddle.jshell.net/1kmum4du/

Answer (score 2):

I used  this [progress bar](http://s3.envato.com/files/2526201/index.html). For more information on this you can go through this [link](http://s3.envato.com/files/2526201/index.html) i.e customization, coding etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myProgressBar = null
var timerId = null

function loadProgressBar(){
myProgressBar = new ProgressBar("my_progress_bar_1",{
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: 300,
    height: 20,
    maxValue: 100,
    labelText: "Loaded in {value,0} %",
    orientation: ProgressBar.Orientation.Horizontal,
    direction: ProgressBar.Direction.LeftToRight,
    animationStyle: ProgressBar.AnimationStyle.LeftToRight1,
    animationSpeed: 1.5,
    imageUrl: 'images/v_fg12.png',
    backgroundUrl: 'images/h_bg2.png',
    markerUrl: 'images/marker2.png'
});

timerId = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (myProgressBar.value >= myProgressBar.maxValue)
        myProgressBar.setValue(0);
    else
        myProgressBar.setValue(myProgressBar.value+1);

},
100);
}

loadProgressBar();
</script>
```

Hope this may be helpful to somenone.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myPer = 35;
$("#progressbar")
    .progressbar({ value: myPer })
    .children('.ui-progressbar-value')
    .html(myPer.toPrecision(3) + '%')
    .css("display", "block");
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the following **doesn't work currently** because browsers do not support it yet, but maybe some day this will help:

At the time of this post `attr()` on other properties than `content` is just a [Candidate Recommendation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)<sup>1</sup>. As soon as it is implemented, one could create a progress bar with just one element (like the HTML 5 `<progress/>`, but with better styling options and text inside)

```
<div class="bar" data-value="60"></div>
```

and pure CSS

```
.bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #003458;
    color: white;
}

.bar:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: attr(data-value %, 0); /* currently not supported */
    content: '';
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.bar:after {
    content: attr(data-value) "%";
}
```

[Here is the currently **not working** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Pzwt/).

---

<sup>1</sup> Cannot imagine why this isn't implemented in any browser. First I'd think that if you have the functionality for `content` already, it should not be too hard to extend that (but of course I don't really know to be honest). Second: The above is just one good example showing how powerful this functionality could be. Hopefully they start to support it soon, or it won't even be part of the final specification.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a progress-bar of any html element that you can set a gradient to. (Pretty cool!) In the sample below, the background of an HTML element is updated with a linear gradient with JavaScript:

```
myElement.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, #57c2c1 " + percentage + "%, #4a4a52 " + percentage + "%)";
```

PS I have set both locations `percentage` the same to create a hard line. Play with the design, you can even add a border to get that classic progress-bar look :)

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/uoL8j147/1/

Answer (score 1):

Though one can [build a progress bar using setInterval and animating its width](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp)

For best performance while animating a progress bar one has to take into account  [compositor only properties and manage layer count](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count).

Here is an example:

```js
function update(e){
  var left = e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
  var width = e.currentTarget.offsetWidth
  var position = Math.floor((e.pageX - left) / width * 100) + 1;
  var bar = e.currentTarget.querySelector(".progress-bar__bar");
  bar.style.transform = 'translateX(' + position + '%)';
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

.progress-bar {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  user-select: none;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #669900;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.5em 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  width: 100%;
}

.progress-bar__bar {
  background-color: #ececec;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.5em 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
Click on progress bar to update value

<div class="progress-bar" onclick="update(event)">
  <div class="progress-bar__bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could recreate the progress bar using CSS3 animations to give it a better look.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JN8kM/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer_div">
    <div class="inner_div">
        <div id="percent_count">

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS/CSS3**

```
.outer_div {
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}

.inner_div {
    width: 5px;
    height: 21px;
    position: relative; top: 2px; left: 5px;
    background-color: #81DB92;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px #6CC47D;
    -webkit-animation-name: progressBar;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#percent_count {
    font: normal 1em calibri;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes progressBar {
    from {
        width: 5px;
    }
    to {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ProgressBar.js](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js). No dependencies, easy API and supports major browsers.

```
var line = new ProgressBar.Line('#container');
line.animate(1);
```

See more examples of usage [in the demo page.](http://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/#examples)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show and hide progress bar inside your php and java script, then follow this step.Its a complete solution, no need of any library etc.

```
           //Design Progress Bar

  <style>
#spinner
{     
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
background-color: white;
z-index: 100;

height: 200px;


width: 300px;
margin-left: -300px;

    /*Change your loading image here*/
   background: url(images/loading12.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat ;

}
  </style>

               //Progress Bar inside your Page

<div id="spinner" style=" display:none; ">
</div>                                

    // Button to show and Hide Progress Bar
<input class="submit" onClick="Show()" type="button" value="Show" /> 
<input class="submit" onClick="Hide()" type="button" value="Hide" /> 

            //Java Script Function to Handle Button Event     
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function Show()
 {       
  document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = 'inline';
 }
function Hide()
 {       
  document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = 'none';
 }

</script>
```

Image link: [Download image from here](http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading12.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *setInterval* to create a progress bar.

```js
function animate() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("bar");   
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#progress-bar-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#bar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress-bar-wrapper">
  <div id="bar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="animate()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was writing up an answer to a similar question that got deleted, so I'm posting it here in case it's of use to anyone.

The markup can be dropped in anywhere and takes up 50px of vertical real estate even when hidden. (To have it take up no vertical space and instead overlay the top 50px, we can just give the `progressContainerDiv` absolute positioning (inside any positioned element) and style the `display` property instead of the `visible` property.)

The general structure is based on code presented in [this Geeks for Geeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-progress-bar-using-javascript/).

```js
const
  progressContainerDiv = document.getElementById("progressContainerDiv");
  progressShownDiv = document.getElementById("progressShownDiv");
let
  progress = 0,
  percentageIncrease = 10;

function animateProgress(){
  progressContainerDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
  const repeater = setInterval(increaseRepeatedly, 100);
  function increaseRepeatedly(){
    if(progress >= 100){
      clearInterval(repeater);
      progressContainerDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
      progressNumberSpan.innerHTML = "";
      progress = 1;
    }
    else{
      progress = Math.min(100, progress + percentageIncrease);
      progressShownDiv.style.width = progress + "%";
      progressNumberSpan.innerHTML = progress + "%";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#progressContainerDiv{
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#progressBackgroundDiv {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 24%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
  
#progressShownDiv {
  width: 1%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#progressNumberSpan{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressContainerDiv">
  <div id="progressBackgroundDiv">
    <div id="progressShownDiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="progressNumberContainerDiv">
    <span id="progressNumberSpan"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="animateProgress()">Go</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<style>
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<body onload="move()">

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">10%</div>
</div>

<script>
var i = 0;
function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 10;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
        elem.innerHTML = width  + "%";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```