# javascript show progress bar while lengthy javascript calculations are in progress?

Tags: javascript, arrays, progress-bar

I am coding a javascript based network application and in which i have to create array of 1000 rec which generate random numbers between 0 and 1 as

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
rec[i] = Math.random();
}
```

it takes some seconds to generate all random numbers and show it on a div so i just want to ask to how to show progress bar while it generating values?

Comment: "now it takes some seconds to generate all random numbers" - it takes seconds to generate 1000 random numbers? seems unlikely

Comment: Add a gif(or animation) before that code and remove that gif after that code.

Comment: are you sure? seemed pretty quick to me http://jsfiddle.net/hdkkm/

Comment: sorry @MitchWheat :) i removed "now" from the question

Comment: yes @andrew on my pc it takes some seconds !!

Comment: okay @Mr_Green i am trying thank you

Comment: @Mr_Green can you share some example code??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951903/how-to-make-a-progress-bar)

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing something daft like writing or appending values to the DOM within the loop - thus forcing the browser to try and redraw the screen each iteration...

example 1: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYrab/) - 4000ms+ (for me)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    rec[i] = Math.random();
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += ('<br/>'+rec[i]);
}
```

example 2: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYrab/1/) - 10ms (or thereabout)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    rec[i] = Math.random();
}
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = rec.join('<br/>');
```

It should not take seconds to generate a 1000 random numbers.  In comparison I'm typing this on an 8 year old laptop with a crappy Centrino processor and a simple test produces somewhere in the region of 420,000 random numbers within a second.