# How can I show a progress bar in Pharo?

Tags: pharo

I have a `do:` in Pharo that takes a long time to process. I'd like to show the progress of it to the user. How is that done in Pharo?

Comment: Dear down voter who left no comment: how is this question worse than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951903 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/238073/1168342 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/3160699/1168342

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are two ways:

1. `Collection` borrows from `UIManager` and supports a `displayingProgress:` `every: milliseconds` variant of `do:`:

   ```
   (1 to: 60)
      do: [ :e | (Delay forSeconds: 0.5) wait "simulate a delay" ]
      displayingProgress: [ :e | 'waiting ' , e asString ] every: 1000
   ```

   You can play with the `every:` on this example to see that if you set it to less than 1000ms, it will update more often (setting it to 100 will show you every value of the interval).

   Also, you can simply use `displayingProgress: 'Waiting...'` to only show the same string the whole time, without a block.
2. Using the `Job` class. Here's a similar solution as above:

   ```
   myColl := 1 to: 20.
   [ :job | 
   myColl
      do: [ :e | 
         job
           progress: e / myColl size;
           title: 'waiting ' , e asString.
         (Delay forSeconds: 0.5) wait ] ] asJob run
   ```